# How to make tiles wrap with Bulma CSS

Tags: css, flexbox, bulma

I'm using the Bulma CSS framework with a Rails app. I have a long list of items and would like to display them in tiles. However, the tiles run off the screen instead of wrapping to the next line.

The [Bulma Documentation](http://bulma.io/documentation/grid/tiles) doesn't address this issue. Since I am creating the tiles dynamically from a variable-length list, explicit nesting as described in their docs isn't so easy and I'd rather have it cleanly wrap to the next line.

Here's what my code basically looks like:

```
<div class="tile is-ancestor">
  <div class="tile is-parent">
    <% @my_list.each do |item| %>
        <div class="tile is-child box">
          <p><%= item %></p>
        </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Since Bulma is based on **flexbox**, I would think there is some equivalent to [`flex-wrap: wrap;`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex-wrap/), but I couldn't find this option yet.

---

**Update:** It's possible to add the `style` `flex-wrap: wrap;`to the parent-container, but is there a Bulma-integrated class flag?

Comment: I just stumbled on this exact issue, and your solution of applying the flex wrap to the parent container worked for me. I think you should make it an answer and accept it. I looked through the docs and could not find any class flag.

Comment: Hei @MForMarlon, thanks for checking up more and for the comment. Okay, I can do that :)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It seems that there is currently no class-flag in Bulma addressing this directly.

However, since Bulma is based on flexbox, it is possible to add the style `flex-wrap: wrap;` to the parent container to achieve the desired outcome.

Answer (score 1):

For the gridsystem Bulma does have a class for this.

If you add `is-multiline` to your `.columns` element it should wrap automatically. (adds `flex-wrap: wrap;` under the hood)

Source: [Bulma column docs](https://bulma.io/documentation/columns/options/)

(Not sure how this applies to tiles, but you could always wrap them into columns)

Answer (score 0):

The DevTools inspector shows that Bulma's `box p` has a default style of `white-space: nowrap`.

Applying `style="white-space: normal!important;"` directly onto the `<p>` tag forced it to wrap as normal and fixed the problem for me.